# Java Buffered Writer to publically accessible location

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to change a program I wrote a while ago. Currently the program handles a few BufferedReader and BufferedWriters with some logic built in. Let me explain how it used to work.

Class used to upload a file:

```
public void getFile(){//Used to upload the ACH file. 

        while(uploadApproval==false){//While upload approval has not been given..

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new object of the JFileChooser class. 

        uploadFile = chooser;//Saves the upload file variable as the chooser response. 

        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("ACH Files", "ach");
        //Sets the allowed file formats for upload. 

        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);//Activates the created file filter.

        chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose ACH file to upload");//Sets the title bar text. 

        //Completes once the user clicks ok. 
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);//
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            uploadApproval=true;
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Class used to set directory

```
public void setDirectory(){//Used to set the directory. 

        while(saveApproval==false){//While the user does not have approval of the save location..

        JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new JFileChooser object.

        saveFile = chooser2;//Sets the save file location to chooser2. 

        chooser2.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);//User is only able to scan for 
        //directories. 

        //Completes once the user clicks okay. 
        int returnValue2 = chooser2.showDialog(chooser2, "Directory to save");
        if(returnValue2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            saveApproval=true;
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }

        }

    }
```

Then later I begin the actual buffered reader/writer process which involves a lot of logic here:

```
location = "//NachaOutput"+randomNumber+".ACH";

        try{

            String sCurrentLine;//String representing the current line. 

            //Pulls the uploaded file. 
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(NachaMain.uploadFile.getSelectedFile()));




            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NachaMain.saveFile.getSelectedFile()+location));
```

Now here is what I need to do. I have been asked to remove the screen where the user selects the directory from the beginning. Instead, the user will select the save directory in the end of the process.

This means that the "SetDirectory" method won't be called at all, therefore this line of code:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NachaMain.saveFile.getSelectedFile()+location));
```

obviously won't work. I need to find some way to replace that file writer location with a generic location that would be the same for all users regardless of their setup. Something along the lines of documents.

I tried doing this:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Libraries\\Documents"+location));
```

but got an exception about an invalid path.

So please help me out and let me know a good path that I could save the file to automatically. That saved file will basically be a "dummy" file. Later in the end of the program I will copy that dummy file to the location the user specifies then delete it, so the location really doesn't matter too much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add more details about the full intended workflow for the file after making the change?  Is the intent that the download would be done to some temporary location first, and then the user would choose the final destination, and then you would rename to that final destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary file using [`File.createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)). It might make cleanup easier if you called [`deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) for the created temporary file.

Comment: Thanks that is very good advice however it doesn't exactly answer my question. How do I declare a generic file location to put that temp file? Can it be used with Buffered reader/writer?

Comment: It creates an actual temporary file that you can write to. Just pass the returned File to the FileWriter constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try that out.